# multi dimensional array in cplex c++ concert tech

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to create a boolean matrix in c++ concert technology. I have defined 
    `typedef IloArray<IloBoolArray> BoolMatrix;`
after that I declared it:    `BoolMatrix Assigned(env)`;  but while trying input data by    `file >> Assigned`, it is showing error (no operator ">>" matches these operands). Please help me to come out of this error.
thanks

Comment: Can I ask what you need boolean matrix for? I would suggest to use usual  `IloNumArray` if you have {0,1} values in your file. Plus, keep in mind that the array in the file should have a specific format that looks like Pythons list, e.g. `[1,2,3,4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it means that either you forgot to declare operator ">>" with passing argument types in your class or library class that you're using doesn't support such operation for these arguments. Can you be more specific in your question?

Answer (score 0):

What the error is telling you is that the compiler cannot find any definition of `operator>>(Type1 LHS, Type2 RHS)` with the arguments you are giving it. `Type1` could be an `std::istream` and `Type2` is `BoolMatrix`.

To allow for what you are trying to do, you would need to define your own implementation of `operator<<`, which takes the types you give it, and operates on those. The function prototype might look like this:

```
void operator<<(std::istream& file, BoolMatrix& matrix) {
  // Read in the values from the stream and add them to matrix
}
```

Also, from the [CPLEX Documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.3/ilog.odms.ide.help/refcppopl/html/classes/IloArray.html), it says:

*The template operator >> makes it possible to read numeric values from a file in the format [x, y, z, ...] where x, y, z are the results of the operator >> for class X. Class X must provide a default constructor for operator >> to work. That is, the statement X x; must work for X. This input operator is limited to numeric values.*

You have two arrays of `IloArrayX`, where X is a bool array for the outer array, and `bool` for the inner array. You can read the bool's from the file using a stream, add them to the inner bool array ( `IloBoolArray`), and then add the inner `IloBoolArray` to the `IloArray`.

Also, from some code samples I found online, it seems that you need to initialise each of the `IloBoolArray`'s, before adding to it.

Here is a sample of what I understand will work (this is untested):

```
typedef IloArray<IloBoolArray>> BoolMatrix;
static constexpr int totalRows = 8;                // Total IloBoolArrays
static constexpr int rowElements = 4;              // Total elements in each bool array

int main() {
  // Create the bool Matrix
  BoolMatrix Assigned(env); 

  bool streamInputVar;                             // Temp variable to read from stream
  const char* inputFilename = "input.txt";         // File to get data from

  std::ifstream inputFile(inputFileName, ios::in); // Try and open file
  if (!inputFile) 
    // Error for failing to open file

  // File open, so read stream into Matrix
  for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; ++i) {
    Assigned.add(IlBoolArray(env));         // Add an IloBoolArray to BoolMatrix
    for (int j = 0; j < rowElements; ++j) {
      if (!(inputFile >> streamInputVar))   // Check that the stream is okay
        // Error for bad stream 
      else 
        Assigned[i].add(streamInputVar);
    }
  }
}
```